# why doenst this code work? in order to get a response from the server in android

Tags: android

```
try {                                                                                                                                       
    HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(
        new HttpGet(requestString));       
    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();                             
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null){
        long temp = Long.parseLong(line);                       
    }   
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: can you tell us what log android give you ? is it triggering the exceptions, simply crashing... it could be your calling a method on a null object, that you parameters are not right that you don't have the permissions in the manifest ...

Comment: I'm sorry but this question is nowhere near a civilized question. That you don't know to format your code right is not really a problem but that you don't even try to format your question right. There is no information provided to what is not working ...

Comment: the error is : the application .... has stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also check for valid response. Why would anyone cast web response to Long ?

Use StringBuilder or simple String for fetching response.

eg.

```
.
.
StringBuilder reponseBuilder=new StringBuilder("");
 while ((line=br.readLine()) != null){ 
    //long temp = Long.parseLong(line);   
    reponseBuilder.append(line);                    
}
.
.
```

And then use it as per scenario may be converting it to a String using:

```
reponseBuilder.toString();
```

and if still your facing same issue then,
Yup, This is truly regarding invalid permission stuff.

Add below code,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

as child of your manifest file. And this will work as magic.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what error you are getting, but my guess would be that this line is giving you problems:

```
long temp = Long.parseLong(line)
```

Are you trying to parse HTTP reply as series of lines where each line contains a long?